# How duplicate entries be prevented while using SqlBulkCopy?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, duplicates

I am importing excel data into sql server using SqlbulkCopy, but the problem is i want to prevent any duplicate records being entered. Is there a way  by which duplicate can be ignored or deleted automatically?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strFileType = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToString().ToLower();
    string strFileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.ToString();

    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Import/" + strFileName + strFileType));
    string strNewPath = Server.MapPath("~/Import/" + strFileName + strFileType);

    string excelConnectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + strNewPath + "; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");

    // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
    {
        var command = new OleDbCommand("Select ID,Data FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);

        connection.Open();

        // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet
        using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // SQL Server Connection String
            string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=ARBAAZ-1B14C081;Initial Catalog=abc;Integrated Security=True";

            con.Open();
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            string s = "select count(*) from ExcelTable";
            string r = "";
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(s, con);

            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
                da1.Fill(dt1);
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            int RecordCount;
            RecordCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
            r = RecordCount.ToString();
            Label1.Text = r;
            con.Close();
            int prv = Convert.ToInt32(r);

            // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "ExcelTable";

                SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapping1 = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("excelid", "id");
                SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapping2 = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("exceldata", "data");

                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapping1);
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapping2);

                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
            }

            con.Open();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            s = "select count(*) from ExcelTable";
            r = "";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);

            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            RecordCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            r = RecordCount.ToString();
            Label1.Text = r;
            con.Close();
            int ltr = Convert.ToInt32(r);

            if (prv == ltr)
            {
                Label1.Text = "No records Added";
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Records Added Successfully !";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can this problem be fixed by creating a trigger to delete duplicates? if yes how? i am a newbie i have never created a trigger.

Another problem is no matter what i try i am unable to get column mapping to work. I am unable to upload data when column names in excel sheet and database are different.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create [INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx)

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX MyIndex ON ExcelTable(id, data) WITH IGNORE_DUP_KEY
```

And when you will insert data with bulk to db, all duplicate values will not inserted.

Comment: wont you need an index on all fields?

Comment: oh, he is importing only id and data :) It is a good solutin but it wouldnt work if duplicate records can actually exist on the table, just need to be ignored on the bulk process

Comment: @user1557976 has only two columns in his table.

Comment: @kmatyaszek my friend you acidently solved a big problem i had one which i did not even mention lol

Answer (score 0):

no, either you manage it on your dr object on you code before you load it into the db (like running a DISTINCT operation) or you create a trigger on the DB to check. The trigger will reduce the bulk insert's performace though.

Another option would be to bulk insert into a temp table and then insert into your destination table FROM your temp table using a select DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

as far as I remember,
you could filter out the redundant rows when importing from the excel file itself.

the following SQL query should be used in the OleDbCommand constructor.

```
var command = new OleDbCommand("Select DISTINCT ID,Data FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);
```